# Let $G$ have odd order. Show that if $\chi\in Irr(G)$ is not principal then $\chi$ can't equal to its conjugate

Tags: group-theory, finite-groups, characters

This is Isaac's exercise 3.16.

> Let $G$ be a group with odd order. Show that if $\chi \in Irr(G)$ is not principle then $\chi$ can't  equal to its conjugate.

my try:
Suppose $\chi = \bar \chi$

By the orthogonality
$[\chi,\bar\chi]=1$

$$\sum_{g\in G} \chi^{2}=|G|$$

I know that the degree divides the the group's order, so

$$\chi(1) \mid \sum_{g\in G-1} \chi^{2}$$

I said $\chi(1)$ is odd ($\chi(1) \mid  |G| $ odd integer)

Also, the summation is an even integer

I don't feel like I am going any closer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $\chi \in Irr(G)$, with $\chi \neq 1_G$ (the trivial character). Apply the orthogonality relation to $\chi$ and $1_G$, then
$$\sum_{x \in G}\chi(x)=0.$$
Now assume that $\chi$ is real-valued. Then $\chi(x)=\overline{\chi(x)}$ (complex conjugate) for all $x \in G$. From the orthogonality formula above one has
$$\chi(1)=-\sum_{x \in G-\{1\}}\chi(x).$$
But $\chi(1) \mid |G|$, so the degree of $\chi$ is odd. The oddness of $|G|$ also implies that for all $x \in G-\{1\}$, $x\neq x^{-1}$, so
$$\sum_{x \in G-\{1\}}\chi(x)=\sum \chi(x)+\chi(x^{-1}),$$
where the last sum is taken over a set of *disjoint pairs* $\{x,x^{-1}\}$. Now $\chi(x)$ is the sum of the eigenvalues of a matrix representing $x$, while $\chi(x^{-1})$ is the sum of the eigenvalues of the inverse of that same matrix. The eigenvalues of the matrix are roots of unity and for a root of unity $\zeta$, one has $\zeta^{-1}=\overline{\zeta}$. Since $\chi$ is real-valued one must have $\chi(x)=\chi(x^{-1})$. It follows that
$$\frac{1}{2}\chi(1)=-\sum_{x}\chi(x).$$
We now have a contradiction: the left hand side is half an odd positive integer, while the right hand side is an algebraic integer.